# How to change the date in Windows 7 by using command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, time

When I try to change the date in Windows 7 using the Command Prompt, I get the error:

> "The required privilege is not held by the client"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your user profile hold the required Administrator permissions, if it doesn't, then it needs to

Answer (score 3):

The *date* command can only be used to set the system date when executed from an elevated (admin) command prompt.

Just search for "command" or "cmd" in the Start Menu, right-click and select *Run as administrator*, then provide necessary credentials or press Yes when the UAC dialog pops up.

Comment: Or press ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Or use `runas` command :)